Is there any programmatic way to detect that a process running under containerd has its stdin and stdout closed?
I am currently exploring workarounds for the problem of processes started by kubectl exec not dying on disconnect described in my other question.
Here are a couple of observations.
If I run the following script on a pod from kubectl exec, it continues to print /dev/tty is available and usable to /tmp/Result even after I kill the kubectl exec command on the client side.
while true; do
sleep 1
if sh -c ": >/dev/tty" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
    echo '/dev/tty is available and usable' >> /tmp/Result
    echo 'PTS output where'
else
    echo '/dev/tty is not available' >> /tmp/Result
fi
done

On the other hand, after I kill the kubectl exec process, when I look at containerd logs on the node that the pod was running on, I see these log messages, which suggests that containerd is well aware that stdin and stdout are not functional after the client process is killed.
journalctl -u containerd
level=info msg="Container exec \"6ad3d92d21ac690f02ded22f9ee84cf272802bdde805bf79ea798f6cb86302a5\" stdin closed"
level=error msg="Failed to pipe \"stdout\" for container exec \"6ad3d92d21ac690f02ded22f9ee84cf272802bdde805bf79ea798f6cb86302a5\"" error="read /proc/self/fd/93: file already closed"

Is there any programmatic way for the process (started by kubectl exec) running inside a container to learn that kubectl exec is dead?
For example, interrogating it directly via API call, making a system call, looking for a signal, or some other means?

If it's important to know whether stdin is a tty or not, your code can use isatty(3).  What are you actually trying to do, though?  There are a couple of problems with kubectl exec – it only targets one Pod of a typical multi-replica Deployment, any changes it makes will get lost when its Pod exits – and I wouldn't normally use it except for debugging purposes.

@DavidMaze, if you look at the original question, you'll see that I'm trying to solve the problem of kubectl exec not killing processes on client disconnect.

The underlying problem is that engineers may start a process for debugging on the pod, such as a rails console, and then go to lunch. If kubectl disconnects because the VPN times out, then that process continues to consume resources on the pod. These sessions can accumulate and eventually cause an OOM.

I've edited the question to have more context inline. Hopefully that is more clear!
